# Is there any C# API for Flyway?

Tags: flyway, evolve

Is there any C# API for Flyway?

I want to include Flyway with a .Net application and not force none Java developers to install Flyway or Maven or Java. Rather have them use tools they are familiar with like Nuget for example.

Answer (score 25):

There is a .NET equivalent now ! It's called **Evolve**. I wrote it because after discovering Flyway on a Java project, I could not do without it in .NET anymore.

**Evolve** has a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/lecaillon/Evolve) and a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Evolve) available for .NET and .NET Core projects. It supports MSBuild and `dotnet build` command.

Hope you'll like it !

Comment: Sounds interesting, however ideally I am looking to use Flyway's C# so all projects can be "standardized" of sorts. Why did you start a new thing, can you not join Flyway's open source and add to that project?

Comment: Evolve is great @Philippe - we have been using Flyway for many years and now use Evolve alongside for our dotnet code. I've even been using it happily on AWS ECS containers running Alpine Linux - very impressed with that.

Answer (score 2):

A matured database migration tool for .Net is Fluent Migrator 
https://github.com/fluentmigrator/fluentmigrator

Comment: Thanks, but I want to use the same DB migration tool cross platform. I am specifically looking for .Net integrations with Flyway and not other DB migration tools.

Answer (score 1):

There is a .NET wrapper around Flyway called Flyway.NET.

- You can get it on nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Flyway.net/
- Repository can be found here: https://github.com/bunomonteiro/flyway.net

Answer (score 0):

No there is not. You can download the CLI tool and then use .NET to call it as a potential solution for what you have in mind. Not sure how you would go about packaging that with nuget, but you should be able to write something to solve your specific problem

Comment: I was hoping that someone could help me with the packaging with nuget part of this.

Comment: ok? so you already have a C# API for Flyway, but you just want to know how to package and publish it for nuget? That changes your original question quite dramatically, don't you agree?

Comment: No - I don't have a C# API but the CLI could be used. No, I don't want the original question changed.

Comment: Okay well, here is a tutorial for creating nuget packages then: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2016/06/28/creating-nuget-packages/

Answer (score 0):

In a very large project we where using [Roundhouse](https://github.com/chucknorris/roundhouse) for db versioning. It's an alternative to flyway that IMO deserves to be considered as it has a certain level of maturity.

I've seen that they have recently introduced support for .Net core but I haven't tested it.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to use the same DB migration tool cross platform. I am specifically looking for .Net integrations with Flyway and not other DB migration tools.